# validation of password and username nodejs mysql

Tags: html, mysql, node.js

I am working on a project and I'm trying to build a login page on nodejs-html by using mysql as database. But my code directly gets to "response.send('Please enter Username and Password!');" part, and shows me that page.(no problem with mysql connection) Why can't i check if the login username and password is right? And go to the next page if true?

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    ....................
});
connection.connect((err) => {
    if(err){ 
    throw err;}
   else console.log("connected");
});

var app = express();
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/login.html'));
});

app.post('/', function(request, response) {
    var username = request.body.user_name;
    var password = request.body.pass;
    console.log(username);

    if (username && password) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ? AND pass = ?', [username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
            console.log(username);
            if (results.length > 0) {
                request.session.loggedin = true;
                request.session.user_name = username;
                response.redirect('/secondPage');
            } else {
                response.send('Incorrect Username and/or Password!');
            }           
            response.end();
        });
    } else {
        response.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
        response.end();
    }
});

app.get('/login', function(request, response) {
    if (request.session.loggedin) {
        response.send('Welcome back, ' + request.session.username + '!');
    } else {
        response.send('Please login to view this page!');
    }
    response.end();
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: If you execute `SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = some_user AND pass = some_pass` in mysql console with values you have passed through the request, do you get any results?

Comment: I've have tried that. question marks were the problem but now I've turned my SQL to : "select * from users" and it works.

Comment: Please please please do not store the person’s password in plain text (readable) like this. Encrypt the password using a password encryption algorithm and store that in your database. Then when they go to sign in you encrypt their password that they just typed and compare the two encrypted values. Storing unencrypted passwords is a massive security issue.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer and always take care of what @nate has said

Comment: @Nate thanks for reminding. For now I store password values in kind of blob and insert the data with AES_ENCRYPT. I keep searching about this.

Comment: @workingonit No problem. And as a reminder to you or anyone else who reads this, the most important thing is making sure that whatever you use to encrypt does not have a decrypt option to it. The idea is to do a one way encryption. You don’t want it to be possible to take your encrypted value and decrypt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.body.user_name is undefined that's why
```

you must have forgot name attribute in your html

> input type="text" **name="user_name"**

also password

```
 <input type="password" name="pass"  >
```

give them suitable name atribute so that body object can access them

Comment: so you say HTML code should include "user_name" as input name? Tried this, and now i can see username on console.log. but still the same problem continues.

Comment: did you forgot to give name attribute to password as name="pass" . user_name is correct